# Showing a list of objects alongside a Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a very simple DetailView (CBV) that shows details about an event. Within this DetailView, I am also showing a sidebar "gadget" that lists 5 events that have approaching deadlines. The logic for showing this "ListView" within a "DetailView" is being defined in my **models.py**, by doing a query of the `Event` model.

Something tells me that this isn't the correct way of going about things. It's currently working...but I'm getting the feeling (after reading through the docs) that this kind of stuff should be moved to the view, rather than the model.

Is there a way to "optimize" this current logic?

In my **views.py**:

```
class SingleEventView(DetailView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'single-event.html'
```

In the *single-event.html* template, I'm showing a list of the 5 closest upcoming events by defining the following in **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Event(models.Model):
    # Model stuff

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['event_date']

    def approaching(self):
        today = date.today()
        approaching_event = Event.objects.exclude(event_date__lt=today)[:5]
        return approaching_event
```

This is allowing me to do the following in my template:

```
<dl>
    {% for approaching in event.approaching %}
        <dt>{{ approaching.deadline|date:"F j" }}:</dt>
        <dd>{{ approaching.title }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Should this `approaching` method be static? Should it be a function? It just seems...wrong. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason you would want this at the model if this method has a proper use case across all uses of instances of your model.

That is, you are not writing it here *only for the view*.

In this particular example - your method is there in the model because you are really using the model instance as a way to call this method in the view.

Think of this another way, if you were not using a class based view, would you still put this method in the model?

So, the issue now is how do you send custom objects to the view in the context when using class based views?

In all class based views (that inherit from `ContentMixin`), you can override the [`get_context_data` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) to return custom objects in the context:

```
import datetime

from yourapp.models import Event

class SingleEventView(DetailView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'single-event.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Get the existing context dictionary, then add
       # your custom object to it before returning it
       ctx = super(SingleEventView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       ctx['approaching'] = Event.objects.exclude(event_date__lt=datetime.date.today())[:5]
       return ctx
```

Of course now in your template:

```
<dl>
    {% for approaching in approaching %}
        <dt>{{ approaching.deadline|date:"F j" }}:</dt>
        <dd>{{ approaching.title }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

If you are planning to use this in different views, it would be better to create a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) so that this object is available in all your views no matter how they are being called.

```
import datetime

from yourapp.models import Event

def upcoming_events(request):
    now = datetime.date.today()
    return {'approaching': Event.objects.exclude(event_date__lt=now)[:5]}
```

Save that in a module, and add that module path to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) keeping the defaults there.

Now you won't have to worry about "manually" sending the list of objects across, it will be available in all views that inherit from `RequestContext` (so all class based views and any view that uses the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render)).

Comment: You can always still keep the `approaching` method as a class method of `Event` and insert the approaching events in the view context using  `ctx['approaching'] = Event.approaching()`. This way you can reuse it in other views.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Still getting used to CBV. Forgot that I could simply append data to the existing context dictionary in CBV.

Comment: @dukebody, thanks for the comment. I only need this in a single view; but that's a great point in the off chance I need to duplicate this functionality across view. Thanks!